# Существует ли какой-то плагин в Android Studio для отчистки ненужных gradle dependencies?

Tags: android, android-studio

За время создания проекта накопилось много dependencies. Но проблема в том, что я уже не помню, какие используются а какие нет. Вот мне и интересно, есть ли какой-то плагин упрощающий задачу? Или всё таки придётся вручную искать не использующиеся dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вряд ли кто-то стал бы утруждать себя написанием такого плагина. Без него всё довольно просто - комментируете строчку с зависимостью и пробуете собрать и запустить проект. Если это получается - зависимость не используется.

Comment: Почему же, есть кое-что: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19379517/15923106.

Comment: @woesss, хм, действительно, спасибо)